# Convert a string to datetime format with 12 hour format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am having a field type DateTime in SQL server database.
I am developing a webservice to fetch date and time.

The date is stored in this format 4/14/2013 10:10:01 PM in database.

Now, I have a webmethod as below:

```
public string GetdataJson(string lastdate)
        {

            DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(lastdate);


            string getvalue = "select * from tblfameface where last_updated >='" + myDateTime  + "'";

            con1 = new SqlConnection(conString1);
            con1.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getvalue, con1);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt1);

            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt1);
            String finalString = "{\"Records\":";
            finalString += jsonString;
            finalString += "}";
            return finalString;

        }
```

But this code is giving me an error of String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
how can I convert string into datetime format like 4/14/2013 10:10:01 PM??
help!

Comment: What is the input you are sending to this webmethod?

Comment: I m passing 4/14/2013 10:10:01 PM

Comment: Just confirming: On which line are you getting the exception? I think it may be unexpected input in parameter `lastdate`

Comment: You have a culture variant which uses 24 hour clock https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx "Because the DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime) method tries to parse the string representation of a date and time using the formatting rules of the current culture, trying to parse a particular string across different cultures can either fail or return different results. If a specific date and time format will be parsed across different locales, use the DateTime.TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime) method or one of the overloads of the TryParseExact.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string getvalue = "select * from tblfameface where
     last_updated >= Convert(DateTime, '" + myDateTime  + "')";
```

or this depending on you SQL data type on column last_updated

```
string getvalue = "select * from tblfameface where
     last_updated >= Convert(DateTime2(7), '" + myDateTime  + "')";
```

Answer (score 7):

You want 12-hour clock  use small hh , You want  the 24-hour clock use capital  HH

```
DateTime formatted =Covert.ToDateTime( lastdate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

If you want to use the 12-hour clock, use tt in the format string to produce the AM/PM designator.

Answer (score 3):

In your format string use `tt` for **PM/AM** part. Here is the code:

```
 DateTime dateTime = 
    DateTime.ParseExact("4/14/2013 10:10:01 PM", 
                        "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This should also works:

```
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse("04/14/2013 10:10:01 PM");
```

Are you sure you are getting the correct string?

Comment: @Hossein Narimani Rad-your code is giving error that no overload method for ParseExact takes 2 parameters

Comment: its not in my case,now wat to do?

Comment: above code is perfectly working..Even Convert.ToDateTime() also working...Please check out with the input....

Comment: Ok, just tell me using a good example of a 12 hour format to tell her that you're converting a string to 12 hour format is a good example? Use something like `2/2/13 23:40:45 PM` and convert it to 12 hours format! Go on.. :/ @Khushbu, did you find anything working? If so let me know please!

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
DateTime.ParseExact(yourString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace query line by

```
string getvalue = "select * from tblfameface where CAST(last_updated AS 
DATETIME)>='" + myDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")  + "'";
```